# Inconsistent/Delayed HTML5 Desktop Push Notifications on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, notifications

I'm writing a chat webapp that needs to be able to trigger desktop push notifications through the notifications API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API

Unfortunately, it seems that the notifications don't show up until I flush it all out by making another notification with this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yoshi6jp/Umc9A/

This is the code that I am using:

```
function triggerDesktopNotification() {
  function makeNotification() {
    var notification = new Notification('AppName', {
      body: 'You have a new message!',
      icon: '/favicon.ico',
    });
    notification.onclick = () => {
      notification.close();
    };
  }

  if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
    makeNotification();
  }
  else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
      if (permission === 'granted') {
        makeNotification();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I can confirm that the code is executing properly by placing `console.log()` immediately after the `new Notification` call. Interestingly, if I put an `alert()` there instead, the notification shows up when I see the alert box (after navigating back into my tab).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right ;

Alert interrupts program stack where it placed i think.Why dont you try to fire it async with setTimeout function like that ?

```
 setTimeout(  function(){
       alert("asd");
     })
```

edited js fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Umc9A/881/)